# Default non indexer properties in C#

Tags: c#, properties, language-features, nullable, default-value

How can you create a default - non indexer - property in C#?

What I mean by this is I can see that I can create indexer default properties as illustrated on [this MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2b6akew6%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) page.

This allows me to do things like

```
Widgets widgets = new Widgets();
Widget result = widgets[1];
```

But what if I want to achieve something like what `Nullable<T>` does?

Where you can take

```
Nullable<decimal> nullDec = 1.23m;
decimal result = nullDec.Value;
```

OR

```
decimal result = (decimal)nullDec;
```

Which I assume is simply a default property implementation to `nullDec.Value`???

Comment: Nullables are special, they have special compiler treatment. Maybe implicit conversions would help, but could you elaborate more what you actually want to do?

Comment: Sorry perhaps I wasn't clear enough. I just want to be able to create a class where I can specify a property which is the default value returned when referencing that class (ie: rather then going obj = myClass.Property - I just wanna go obj = myClass)

Comment: @Maxim - note that while the answers show a few ways that you *could* do this, this syntax is really intended for conversions - *not* for a "default property"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Nullable<T>` has special handling in the compiler, but you can do *most* of that by adding implicit or explicit static conversion operators.

For example, for type `Foo` you can add an operator:

```
public static implicit operator string(Foo value)
{
    return "abc";
}
public static implicit operator Foo(int value)
{
    ...
}
```

allowing:

```
Foo foo = ..
string s = foo; // uses string(Foo value)
```

and

```
int i = 123;
Foo foo = i; // uses Foo(int value)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you inspect the code of Nullable{T} you will see that the explicit cast implementation is like this:

```
public static explicit operator T(Nullable<T> value)
{
    return &value.Value;
}
```

So yes you are right.

Comment: It is what JustDecompile says. I think it is.

Answer (score 1):

The way `Nullable<T>` does it is by providing an [explicit conversion operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131345.aspx) to `T`.

So perhaps you are looking for something like:

```
public static explicit operator Widget(Widgets widgets)
{
     // Argument checks here.
     return widgets[0];     
}
```

which would let you do:

```
Widgets widgets = ..
Widget firstWidget = (Widget)widgets;
```

This does look like a *really* dodgy and unintuitive API to me so I don't recommend doing this at all. Why not just stick to standard indexers?

Answer (score 0):

Not very sure if I correct understant what you're asking for. Wouldn't be enough to implement cast operators on returning type to achieve what you want?

If it's not what you intend, please explain.

Answer (score 0):

Such kind of features are compiler syntactic sugar (in IL code they all are converted to same low level code), so basically it won't be possible to do this without modifying the C# compiler source.